# Remove all spaces from text string

Tags: marketing-cloud

In marketing cloud, I am trying to find records where the post code does not match in two different fields but I'm running into an issue due to different spacing making the same postcode look different. Is there a way I can remove all spacing in both fields? Similar to TRIM in Excel but within the string rather than just the ends.

```
select *
from Postcode_match
where PostcodeA != PostcodeB
```

Comment: Can you please try with "SELECT REPLACE(Your Attribute, '   ', '')". ?

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you!

Comment: Also you might consider resolving the root problem - data quality. At least if its in your hands.

Comment: You are Welcome @nc_analyst!. Please mark it as the right answer. It will help for others in future. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please update the Query like below:

```
Select Replace(PostcodeA,' ','') as PostcodeA, Replace(PostcodeB,' ','') as PostcodeB
from Postcode_match
where PostcodeA != PostcodeB
```

This will remove all the space in the attribute.

Comment: This throws an error.  Something about unknown column Your Attribute to remove space?? Hahahaha ... j/k, but you might consider using the value in OP's question :)

Comment: Hahaha that's funny @BillMote. I have edited my answer as per the question. Thanks for your suggestion!